# Figma Api fails to get large files

Tags: figma, figma-api

I am writing a crawler that looks through all the Figma files in a project and finds a certain kind of node. I am using this npm package --> https://www.npmjs.com/package/figma-api which uses the Figma REST API under the hood.

Looking at the [API documentation](https://www.figma.com/developers/api#get-files-endpoint) You have to use the GET file endpoint which:

> Returns the document referred to by :key as a JSON object.

This JSON is a tree of Nodes which represents the entire Figma File.

One of my files is quite large and when I try to fetch it I get the following error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (/workspaces/figmaDesignTracker/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/workspaces/figmaDesignTracker/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/workspaces/figmaDesignTracker/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:269:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  config: {
    url: 'https://api.figma.com/v1/files/<FILE-ID>?',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'X-Figma-Token': '<API KEY>',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.4'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    method: 'get',
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    strictContentLength: false,
    _contentLength: 0,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: false,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'api.figma.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'api.figma.com',
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 5,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _header: 'GET /v1/files/<FILE-ID>? HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'X-Figma-Token: <API KEY>\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.21.4\r\n' +
      'Host: api.figma.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype],
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
    path: '/v1/files/<FILE-ID>?',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 400,
      statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://api.figma.com/v1/files/<FILE-ID>?',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 28,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'api.figma.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://api.figma.com/v1/files/<FILE-ID>?',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: true,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'x-figma-token': [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(errored)]: null,
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
  },
  response: {
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'content-length': '77',
      connection: 'close',
      date: 'Thu, 04 May 2023 13:38:37 GMT',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'Content-Type, X-Figma-Token, Authorization',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
      vary: 'X-Figma-Token,Authorization',
      'x-cache': 'Error from cloudfront',
      via: '1.1 ed9cefde6d1b28548496972ee2c72448.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
      'x-amz-cf-pop': 'LHR50-P8',
      'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400',
      'x-amz-cf-id': 'ibKLFlSBQAKcnHxA_G3wgrS1RtmUHpmsPQCF4DE7tIIKsA4RbYCsjQ==',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload'
    },
    config: {
      url: 'https://api.figma.com/v1/files/<FILE-ID>?',
      headers: [Object],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      transitional: [Object],
      method: 'get',
      data: undefined
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /v1/files/<FILE-ID>? HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'X-Figma-Token: <API KEY>\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.21.4\r\n' +
        'Host: api.figma.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: '/v1/files/<FILE-ID>?',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'api.figma.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: true,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    data: {
      status: 400,
      err: 'Render timeout, try requesting fewer or smaller images'
    }
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

Of which right at the bottom it says:

> data: {
> status: 400,
> err: 'Render timeout, try requesting fewer or smaller images'
> }

This is strange because this API endpoint does not mention anything about images and there is a specific endpoint that is called GET image which would surely be for images.

My question is: Is there a way to get the JSON for the large file? I think the answer is no (not easily anyway as I would probably have to get nodes in chunks and then piece the JSON back together again -- haven't tried this).

I have only tried the GET file endpoint and expected it to give me the JSON of the Figma file.

Comment: Have you gathered any additional information about this? I've just run into this problem today.

Comment: @borrimorri I have opened an issue on Github for it https://github.com/figma/figma-api-demo/issues/46. Other than that I believe that there is no current way around this.